# Problem solving limit infinity/infinity.

Tags: calculus, limits

I cannot solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
 \frac {(3x^2-4)  \left( \sqrt [3]{2x^2+1}+1
 \right)^2}{ (2x-1) \left( 4-\sqrt {8x^3-2}
 \right)x^{3/2}}$$

I make this:
$${\frac { \left( 3\,{x}^{2}-4 \right)  \left( \sqrt [3]{2\,{x}^{2}+1}+1
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2}
 \right) {x}^{3/2}}} =3\,{\frac {\sqrt {x} \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2/3}}{ \left( 2\,x-
1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) }}-4\,{\frac {
 \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2/3}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-
\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) {x}^{3/2}}}+6\,{\frac {\sqrt {x}\sqrt [3]
{2\,{x}^{2}+1}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2}
 \right) }}-8\,{\frac {\sqrt [3]{2\,{x}^{2}+1}}{ \left( 2\,x-1
 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) {x}^{3/2}}}+3\,{\frac 
{\sqrt {x}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2}
 \right) }}-4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{
x}^{3}-2} \right) {x}^{3/2}}}$$

then

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}3\,{\frac {\sqrt {x} \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2/3}}{ \left( 2\,x-
1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) }}
$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-4\,{\frac { \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2/3}}{ \left( 2\,x-1
 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) {x}^{3/2}}}
$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}6\,{\frac {\sqrt {x}\sqrt [3]{2\,{x}^{2}+1}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right) 
 \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) }}
$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-8\,{\frac {\sqrt [3]{2\,{x}^{2}+1}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-
\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2} \right) {x}^{3/2}}}
$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}3\,{\frac {\sqrt {x}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{
3}-2} \right) }}
$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2}
 \right) {x}^{3/2}}}
$$

but I cannot solve this

NOTE: I cannot use L'hopital for finding this limit.

Comment: Find the highest power of x in the numerator and the denominator.  As x goes to infinity this term is going to dominate.  If you have a higher power in the denominator the limit is going to 0.  If the higher power is in the numerator, it is going to infinity.  If they are equal, then limit will equal the ratio of their coefficients.

Comment: This posting does a pretty thorough job of making the MathJax code a lot more complicated and messy than it needs to be.  Presumbaly one of those web pages that are alleged to exist that write the code for you, since it's hard to imagine a human doing this. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = b$ then continuity of multiplication shows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = ab$.

Write $${1 \over 2x-1} = {1 \over x(2-{1 \over x})} ={1 \over x} {1 \over  2 - {1 \over x}},$$ then since
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over  2 - {1 \over x}} = {1 \over 2} \text{ and } \lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over x} = 0$$ we see that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over 2x-1} = 0.$$

Write $${1 \over 4 -\sqrt{8 x^3 - 2} } = {1 \over x^{3 \over 2}( {4 \over  x^{3 \over 2}}-\sqrt{8  - {2 \over x^3}} )} = {1 \over x^{3 \over 2}} { 1 \over  {4 \over  x^{3 \over 2}}-\sqrt{8  - {2 \over x^3}} )} .$$
Then $$\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over x^{3 \over 2}} = 0$$ and 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over {4 \over  x^{3 \over 2}}-\sqrt{8  - {2 \over x^3}} )} = -{ 1 \over \sqrt{8}},$$ and so
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}  {1 \over 4 -\sqrt{8 x^3 - 2} } = 0.$$

You can see that $\lim_{x \to \infty}  { 1 \over x^{3 \over 2}} = 0$.

It follows that the limit is $0\cdot 0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The total power of $x$ in the numerator is $2 + 4/3 = 10/3.$ The total power of $x$ in the denominator is $1 + 3/2 + 3/2 = 4.$ The denominator wins: The limit must be $0.$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}
 {\frac { \left( 3\,{x}^{2}-4 \right)  \left( \sqrt [3]{2\,{x}^{2}+1}+1
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-\sqrt {8\,{x}^{3}-2}
 \right) {x}^{3/2}}}$

$\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}
 {\frac { \left( 3\,{x}^{2}-4 \right)  \left( (2x^2+1)^{1/3}+1
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 4-(8x^3-2)^{1/2}
 \right) {x}^{3/2}}}$

find the highest power of x in the numerator and the denominator.

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}
 \frac{3*2^{2/3}x^{10/3} + ax^n + bx^m... }{2*8^{3/2}x^4+cx^{p}+dx^q..} $

with $m <n < 10/3$ and $p<q < 4$

Divide top and bottom by $x^4$

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}
 \frac{3*2^{2/3}x^{-2/3} + ax^{n-4} + bx^{m-4}... }{2*8^{3/2}+cx^{p-4}+dx^{q-4}...} $

as x goes to infinity all the terms with x to a negative power go to 0, leaving a zero in the numerator and a constant in the denominator.

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}
 \frac{3*2^{2/3}x^{-2/3} + ax^{n-4} + bx^{m-4}... }{2*8^{3/2}+cx^{p-4}+dx^{q-4}...}=0 $